# Configure Dropwizard ObjectMapper for configuration to ignore unknown

Tags: dropwizard, objectmapper

With an `ObjectMapper` (`com.fasterxml.jackson.databind`) it's possible to specify that it should ignore unknown properties. This can either be done by adding `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)` on a class level or by setting it as default behavior in the mapper. However, when doing this in the `initialize()` method of `Application<MyConfiguration>` it doesn't seem to have an effect.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = bootstrap.getObjectMapper();
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
```

It still fails for unknown properties in the configuration file. How does one configure Dropwizard to ignore unknown properties?

Comment: What is the version of DW?

Comment: The version I have is 0.7.1. Apparently a newer version comes with more ability to actually configure the ModelMapper, but this version enforces the `true` flag on `FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES ` no matter what the configuration was before.

Answer (score 8):

The reason configuring `DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES` for `bootstrap.getObjectMapper()` doesn't have the desired effect is that `ConfigurationFactory` (the class later on used to parse the configuration) is enabling that particular feature of the object mapper in its constructor (see [here](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/901a459af922491bb556d62e046d1475760fb8ce/dropwizard-configuration/src/main/java/io/dropwizard/configuration/ConfigurationFactory.java#L60)):

```
public ConfigurationFactory(Class<T> klass,
                            Validator validator,
                            ObjectMapper objectMapper,
                            String propertyPrefix) {
    ...
    this.mapper = objectMapper.copy();
    mapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
    ...
}
```

It's not possible to change the behaviour of `ConfigurationFactory` directly but Dropwizard provides means to override the factory that creates it, `ConfigurationFactoryFactory`, via `Boostrap.setConfigurationFactoryFactory()`. This allows to replace the real `ObjectMapper` with a proxy that doesn't allow to override the configuration and pass it to `ConfigurationFactory`:

```
  bootstrap.setConfigurationFactoryFactory(
      (klass, validator, objectMapper, propertyPrefix) -> {
          return new ConfigurationFactory<>(klass, validator,
              new ObjectMapperProxy(objectMapper), propertyPrefix);
      }
  );
```

The code for `ObjectMapperProxy` that ignores attempts to enable `FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES` it below:

```
private static class ObjectMapperProxy extends ObjectMapper {

    private ObjectMapperProxy(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        super(objectMapper);
    }

    private ObjectMapperProxy(ObjectMapperProxy proxy) {
        super(proxy);
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectMapper enable(DeserializationFeature feature) {
        // do not allow Dropwizard to enable the feature
        if (!feature.equals(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES)) {
            super.enable(feature);
        }
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectMapper copy() {
        return new ObjectMapperProxy(this);
    }

}
```

Note that besides overriding `enable` to skip `FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES` `copy` is also implemented (together with an additional constructor) as `ConfigurationFactory` requires the object mapper to support copying.

While the solution above works it's obviously a workaround and I suggest upgrading to a newer Dropwizard version instead. The new Dropwizard makes `ObjectMapper` configuration easier to override (e.g. see [this Dropwizard commit](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/commit/1e40fef4f4e8f048885b7ce6067bd9cd87a749b2#diff-2857a495260dacab031b1791f6bde06d) available in Dropwizard 1.1.x).

Answer (score 3):

You need to disable that feature with:

```
bootstrap.getObjectMapper().disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
```

**UPDATE:** The feature disable works for the API resources but not for the configuration YAML. Instead, you need to add the annotation below (same as mentioned on the question) to the configuration class:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
```

Comment: No, that does not work unfortunately. I tried (1) only disabling and (2) disabling first and then configuring it to `false` but both gave me the error: `* Unrecognized field at: blabla Did you mean?: ...`.

Comment: I can just add here also that the version of Dropwizard that I'm using (0.7.1) apparently enforces the `true` flag on ModelMapper no matter what you set the configuration to.

Comment: @Myone I have just test disabling this feature in DW 0.7.1 and it worked for me. I have created a simple application for this: https://github.com/andremanuelbarbosa/SOQ47676034

Comment: I have checked out your code locally and while disabling the feature won't give you any errors it won't have any effect either for the reasons described in my answer. You can test that by adding `unknown: true` to `conf.yml` which would lead to the error Myone mentions.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @raindev. Interesting, the disable feature works for resources consumed via the endpoints but not on the application configuration YAML. I have removed the disable feature code and added the JsonIgnoreProperties annotation on the configuration class and that seems to solve the issue (code updated in GH).

Comment: Right, that's consistent with the fact that `ConfigurationFactory` copies the object mapper before enabling `FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES`. That means the object mapper used for API serialization is not affected by the same problem.